# Jasmine test with angular ng-mock not working with controller and promise

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, testing, jasmine, angularjs-ngmock

I have been playing a bit with the following code and I am not able to find the issue, the test fails wit the following message: "Expected undefined not to be undefined."

I have a Service which returns a promise to my controller. In the controller, I am using $q.all to do some stuff immediately after I get the promise resolved.

I tried to follow this example, but the big difference I see is that in the example it has the call in the root of the controller and I have the service call inside of the method "$scope.CustomerTest" so I have this additional line to before the apply ( $scope.$apply() ) "$scope.CustomerTest('Mr');":

http://www.bradoncode.com/blog/2015/07/13/unit-test-promises-angualrjs-q/

This is my test code:

```
var $scope;
var $q;
var deferred;
var $httpBackend;

//Inject the module "before each test"
beforeEach(angular.mock.module('marketingApp'));

beforeEach(inject(function ($controller,_$httpBackend_,  _$rootScope_, _$q_, marketingService) {
    $q = _$q_;
    $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;

    // We use the $q service to create a mock instance of defer
    deferred = _$q_.defer();

    // Use a Jasmine Spy to return the deferred promise
    spyOn(marketingService, 'getTitleSuggested').and.returnValue(deferred.promise);

    // Init the controller, passing our spy service instance
    $controller('customerController', {
        $scope: $scope,
        marketingService: marketingService
    });
}));

it('should resolve promise', function () {
    // Setup the data we wish to return for the .then function in the controller
    var titles = [{ "Id": 1, "Name": "Mr" }];

    deferred.resolve(titles);

    $httpBackend.when('GET', '/MarketingCustomers/GetTitleSuggested')
        .respond(200, titles);

    //I call to the controller method here.
    $scope.CustomerTest('Mr');

    $scope.$apply();

    // Since we called apply, not we can perform our assertions
    //expect($scope.TitlesTest).not.toBe(undefined);
    expect($scope.SelectedCustomerTitle).toEqual('Mr');
    //expect($scope.error).toBe(undefined);
});
```

And this is the plunker:

```
http://plnkr.co/edit/3IMzqH1yKW8kazZFWaA0?p=preview
```

Commenting the first test (it) of the controller.spec.js the other two test works. Any help please?

Comment: The reason you couldn't add the link normally is that we expect a [mcve] to be included in the question itself, not only on some other site.

Comment: Let me repeat part of my comment: **to be included in the question itself, not only on some other site.**

Comment: Got it now, thanks. Well I checked it many times and searched for solutions and I was no a le to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved my issue here is again the plunker if someone has similar problem, hopefully it can helps.

Here is the test:

```
describe('CustomerController.js', function() {

var results = [{
 "Id": 1,
 "Name": "Mr"
}];

var $controller;
var $q;
var $rootScope;
var $scope;
var marketingService;

beforeEach(angular.mock.module('marketingApp'));

beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_, $controller, _$q_, 
_marketingService_) {
$scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
$q = _$q_;
$rootScope = _$rootScope_;
marketingService = _marketingService_;

$controller('customerController', {
  $scope: $scope,
  $rootScope: $rootScope
});

spyOn(marketingService, 'getTitleSuggested').and.callFake(function() {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  deferred.resolve(results);
  return deferred.promise;
});

}));

it('It should call the service" ', function() {

$scope.CustomerTest('Mr');
expect(marketingService.getTitleSuggested).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Mr');
});


it('It should populate the "$scope.TitlesTest" ', function() {

$scope.CustomerTest('Mr');
$rootScope.$apply();

expect($scope.hello).toEqual('Hello Mr Marcos');
expect($scope.Titles[0].Name).toBe('Mr');
expect($scope.Titles).toBe(results);
});
```

});

and this is the plunker:
    http://plnkr.co/edit/3IMzqH1yKW8kazZFWaA0?p=preview

Comment: What did you change?